# TeX Live: double backslashes are being ignored

Tags: texlive

I had this question answered yesterday for a MiKTeX installation, but when I tried to update MiKTeX, the installation became corrupted, so I decided to try out TeX Live on Windows 7.

I installed the entire distribution for TeX Live 2016, and have run

```
c:\ tlmgr update --all
```

I tried a simple example document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{Test Document \\ Subtitle}
\author{My Name \\my email}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\begin{tabular}{l c r}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

When I run `pdflatex` on this document it works fine, but if I change the document class from `article` to `report`, the backslashes in the title, author commands are ignored.

Log from the `pdflatex` run using the report environment is as follows:

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.1.10)  11 JAN 2017 11:42
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./report.tex
(./report.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2016/04/23 3.9r Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count88
\U@D=\dimen103
)
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
))
No file report.aux.
\openout1 = `report.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 7.
[1

{c:/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 9.
 [1]
(./report.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 653 strings out of 493013
 7735 string characters out of 6137008
 65903 words of memory out of 5000000
 4265 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 6675 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,6n,23p,176b,191s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
<c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr1
0.pfb><c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><c:/
texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb>
Output written on report.pdf (2 pages, 30534 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 23 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 15 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Since I am going to be writing some rather large documents which I would like broken up into chapters and sections etc, the report document class seems best, but there are going to be a lot of tables included, so I need the backslashes to work properly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any difference in the behaviour between `report` and `article` regarding the backslashes, only the table is shifted to the next page

Comment: @Christian,  with the report class the two lines of my title and author are printed on the same line for me.

Comment: Not for me, however... e.g. the `\author` commands sets `\@author` which is itself used in a `tabular` environment, so `\\\` is actually a linefeed in a tabular environment

Comment: Neither do I have the problem.  Works as expected.  Strange behaviour.  I even do use the same report version from the same date.  Does it help, switching from `report` to `scrreprt`?

Comment: the behaviour here is always going to be the same between texlive and miktex, the fact that you asked the same question for both systems suggests that you have some local files somewhere that are disturbing things it is not anything anyone else will be able to reproduce. Whatever you did yesterday to fix the miktex question you should do again for this texlive setup.

Comment: Hi, changing the class from report to scrreprt doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Yesterday, I re-instgalled mikTex and that worked, but when I tried running the update process, something broke, because after that any time I tried to run pdflatex it complained that a dll file was missing.

Comment: Could the problem be that I have cygwin64 installed on this system and texlive is included in that installation.  My windows texlive appears first in the path, but I just wonder if it cou ld be getting confused.

Comment: the above log appears to show that all the files used are from the same installation, are you sure you are looking at the correct output add `\showoutput` to your preamble and then repost the resulting log